# Timestamp not current in android

Tags: java, android, time, timestamp, long-integer

I have a very simple timestamp function in an Android app. I have had something similar working multiple times before, but for some reason the function does not update....

```
 public class HelperFunctions {

// ..some more functions


    public static String generateTimestamp(){

        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("generatetimestamp "+ String.valueOf(Math.round(millis/1000)));
        return String.valueOf(Math.round(millis/1000));
    }


}
```

Now i used this function in an already present runnable in my app, just to run it a lot of times and see how it developed...

```
 private final Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateGraphics(); //the reason for the runnable
            timestamp = HelperFunctions.generateTimestamp(); // my malfunctioning function
        }
    };
```

This is my output:

```
03-26 00:23:48.314: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.364: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.424: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.474: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.524: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.574: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.634: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.684: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.734: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.794: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.864: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.914: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:48.974: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.034: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.094: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.164: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.214: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.274: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.324: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.384: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.454: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.514: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.574: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.674: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.784: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.854: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:49.924: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.004: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.074: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.134: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.194: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.264: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.354: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.414: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.474: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.534: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.594: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.654: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.714: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.774: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.834: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.894: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:50.954: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.004: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.064: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.114: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.174: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.234: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.294: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.344: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.404: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.464: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.514: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.574: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.624: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.684: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.744: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.834: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.894: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:51.954: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:52.004: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:52.054: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:52.104: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
03-26 00:23:52.154: I/System.out(8345): generatetimestamp 1395789824
```

etc.

The timestamp is lagging for some reason, and stays static... but it should be changing! 
Does anyone knows why it doesnt change? I think its very weird... It seems like the system.getmillis is stuck or so.

Don't know if it matters, but i am running this on a galaxy tab 10.1 with Cyanogenmod.

Comment: It's weird that the timestamp is at 04:48 but your log entries are in the past. I also can't find any glaring references to issues like this on the internet. Can you post a completely compilable minimal example?

Comment: Post more code in particular how you're calling that method - don't just say "I put my function behind some button...". Your logcat is looking wrong - for instance, how could you have pressed the button three times within the same millisecond? There are three entries for `03-25 23:04:09.274` for example.

Comment: also try to print out without rounding or division, just print out the system time to check

Comment: I edited my question a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your device date and time setting. If date and time is right than use below code to getTime.

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 String test = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
 Log.d("TEST Date", test);
```

or just

```
return cal.getTime();
```

It might help you.

Comment: Still makes no sense why my system gives me the wrong time, but this worked! Thanks